# How to draw 3D in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, 3d

```
        import numpy as np
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

        a = np.array([[6, 2, 3, 1], [-3, -2, 4, 1], [5, -6, 2, 1], [-1, -1, 6, 0]])
        b = np.array([28, 31, 53, -34])
        θ = linalg.solve(a, b)
        print(θ)

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

        plt.show()
```

I have already calculate the coefficient, how can I draw a 3D figure in Python?

Comment: or how can I just use the point to get 3D

Comment: Your shapes do not match a-> (4,4) b->(4,) , O-> (4,) Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: there is T = θ1x + θ2y + θ3z + θ4, I need to use linear regression to find (θ1, θ2, θ3, θ4). and I can use the table (T, x, y, z)=[28,6,2,3], [31,-3,-2,4], [53,5,-6,2], [1, 7, 3, -2], [35, 6, 4, -8]. that is what I need to do, I think x-y-z is 3D? or is 2D??

Comment: I'm able to plot  θ1x + θ2y + θ3z  but with  θ4 it's a bit problemetic, Btw you are right it's a 3d line equation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.